# How to correctly implement an Action?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to implement an `Action` `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action` that will be added to a menu for a `TableViewer` of a view in Eclipse. The menu state(checked or unchecked) should decide if the view will be filled with data at some time based on some selections in the project explorer.

For the moment I created my own class that extends Action. Here I'm changing a variable in the `run method`. This variable is then checked from another class to see if the view should be triggered or not.

Is this the right approach or I can do this using the current implementations of `Action` class ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by "triggering the view". If I understand you correctly, you have some sort of button that you want to be active/passive depending on the state of your table. If this is all happening inside the same view anyway, why not just add a selection listener and call setEnabled()?